# Quartz running by default inside Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I am running a vanilla instance of Tomcat 5.5 which I downloaded from Apache.  I just noticed that when I installed lambda probe that there are about 10 Quartz threads running inside my Tomcat instance.  Is this something that needs to be run all the time?  Can I turn this off?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your Tomcat is vanilla. Tomcat doesn't come with Quartz. You must have a webapp starting these threads. You just need to remove the app.

If you install the Lambda Probe on the Tomcat, the probe itself may start some Quartz threads but that's needed for monitoring.